# People getting more than 200 reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I saw yesterday people with a reputation points gain of more than 200 per day.

How is this possible?

If they cheat or a bug, should one report it?

He joined two months ago, and he got 4 K!!

[image]

And more than one day.

Comment: Points for accepted answer *(15)* and bounties don't count towards daily limit of 200 points.

Comment: See [How does Reputation work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: 4K in two months is about 65 points/day. You don't have to get close to the daily rep limit to reach that. If you look at the results of the rep leagues, the top gainers are normally around 11-12K per month.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are some occurrences that don't count for the rep cap:

- Accepted answer. The +15 from an accepted answer does not count towards the reputation cap.
- Bounties.
- Accepting an answer (the +2).
- Association bonus.
- Account merging.

Comment: What refunds? If I downvoted an answer and it got deleted then the +1?

Comment: ...And merged accounts.

Comment: @Srikanth Yes, if an answer you downvoted gets deleted then that +1 rep does not count towards the rep cap.

Comment: So in short you say only up and down votes count towards rep cap

Comment: @Srikanth And suggested edits.

Comment: @ProgramFox: no, it does count. In that the *original vote* is undone and that day's cap is recalculated. Downvote rep cost being refunded is not a route around the cap.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, ok, I removed it from the list.